# How to stop Rails app crashing due to form_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have an issue with my Rails App which just doesn't make sense. I have a form_tag so that the user can select a date, which is then passed to the controller. All I need it to do is reload the page with the selected date in the URL as params. This same code works elsewhere in my application, but in this instance it crashes the app.

The app completely freezes in both development and production (Heroku). I cannot figure out why.

Here is the form:

````
      <%= form_tag new_reservation_path, method: :get do %>
        <%= date_field_tag 'reservation_date', params[:reservation_date], class: "button-standard", style: "display: inline-block;", placeholder: "DD-MM-YYYY" %>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(:room, params[:room]) %>
        <%= submit_tag 'next', class: "button-standard", style: "display: inline-block;" %>
        <br>
        <br>
      <% end %>```
````

Comment: What do to the logs say?

Comment: This is the weird part. There is no error in the logs, it completes the process but fails to reload the page. Activity monitor tells me that Ruby is then using 97% of my CPU, and then localhost is unresponsive.

Comment: Hmm, try commenting out some parts or putting a break-point to pinpoint the line that is causing this.

Comment: It is the date params that are crashing the app. Just having those params in the url crashes the app, but since there is no error I don't know why. I entered them manually into the address bar and it crashed. There isn't a problem with the form it would seem.

Comment: Infinite loop somewhere maybe?

Comment: Anything funky in the routes definition?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include an example of a URL that breaks it?  The controller method might also help.